# ExoPlayer : how to set the quality of video according to bandwidth

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I am really stuck at this , i am building a live stream tv app ,
where the player automatically select the quality of the stream according to bandwidth .
I followed answers related this issue here in stackoverflow 
but its seems didnt work , i dont know what i am missing or miss understanding.

please look at me code below .....
is this the correct way , or i should have like list of urls with different reoultions , but how to the player could select i dont know

thanks in advance .

```
       private String hlsVideoUri = "http://stream/1080p.m3u8";
     TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory;

        trackSelectionFactory = new 
      AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);


    TrackSelector trackSelector = new 
    DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);
    DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDataSourceFactory = new 
    DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "Tv"), 
    bandwidthMeter);
    // 1. Create a default TrackSelector
    Handler mainHandler = new Handler();

    Log.d("rashed"," "+bandwidthMeter.getBitrateEstimate());
    // 2. Create a default LoadControl
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();


    // 3. Create the player
    player =
            ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                    this, trackSelector);

    simpleExoPlayerView = (PlayerView) findViewById(R.id.playerview);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
```

//

```
    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.

    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
  HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =new   



   HlsMediaSource.Factory(defaultDataSourceFactory).
    createMediaSource(Uri.parse(hls 
  VideoUri),mainHandler, new MediaSourceEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onLoadStarted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, 
  Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, 
  long 
   mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadCompleted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int 
  trackType, 
  Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, 
  long 
  mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long 
  loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadCanceled(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, 
  Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, 
 long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long 
 loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

}

  @Override
   public void onLoadError(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, 
   Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, 
   long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long 
   loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded, IOException error, boolean wasCanceled) 
   {

   }

@Override
public void onUpstreamDiscarded(int trackType, long mediaStartTimeMs, long 
 mediaEndTimeMs) {

}

@Override
public void onDownstreamFormatChanged(int trackType, Format trackFormat, int 
 trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaTimeMs) {

   }
  });



    player.prepare(hlsMediaSource);
    simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

}

Comment: Do you want to capture bandwidth or Video track switching is not happening?

Comment: what i want is , the player should select quality of video according to bandwidth ,so video track switching  is not happening

Comment: I dont see any issue with your code. You have to pass same instance of bandwidthMeter to both AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory and DefaultDataSourceFactory which you are already doing this. You can verify if bandwidth is getting calculated or by setting BandwidthMeter.EventListener.

Comment: Hi Sarvan , thanks for answering , the method i saw fro bandwidth is bandwidthMeter.getBitrateEstimate() and is returning (-1) so i don't know if that is correct, also  please kindly correct me if I am wrong, when we say video track switching, is it done in the server side or in android , what i mean by saying in android that , should i have like 3 different URLs with different resolutions  in Android , or one adaptive url and exoplayer will automatically adapt to best possible quality ?? thanks